# White UINavigation Bar but the back button working fine

Tags: uinavigationbar

In my application, I customised the `UINavigationController` by adding `UIImageView` and `UITextField` to it. And in the pushed views, I want to `UINavigationController` looks normal.

Here's the code:

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    CGRect frame = CGRectMake(0, 20, 320, 44);

    self.navigationController.navigationBar.frame = frame;
    self.navigationController.navigationBar.barStyle = UIBarStyleBlack;
    self.navigationController.navigationBar.tintColor = [UIColor blackColor];
    for (UIView *view in self.navigationController.navigationBar.subviews) {
        if ((view.tag == 10001) || (view.tag = 10002)) {
            [view removeFromSuperview];
        }
    }
}
```

However, what i get is like white `UINavigationBar` with `UIBarStyleBlack` back button.

Image:

[image: Bug]